Proving the equivalence of $P_t = P_{\text{ref}} \,e^{\gamma\Delta T}$ and $\Delta P=P_{\text{ref}} \,\gamma\,\Delta T$
In ocean biogeochemistry, we often calculate the changes in partial pressure of carbon dioxide, $P$, due to changes in temperature $\Delta T$. Let's call my reference $P_{\text{ref}}$ and its new value at time $t$  due to varying temperature is $P_t$ so that $\Delta P = P_t - P_{\text{ref}}$. Two equations are often used in this context to calculate either $\Delta P$ or $P_t$ directly, namely:
$$P_t = P_{\text{ref}} \; e^{\gamma \Delta T} \tag1$$
and
$$\Delta P = P_{\text{ref}} \; \gamma\; \Delta T \tag2$$
where $\gamma = 0.0423^\circ\text{C}^{-1}$ is a constant sensitivity coefficient for temperature.
I would like to prove that they both are equivalent, or to derive (1) from (2) or the other way around, but I get stuck at $\ln(P_t) - \ln(P_{\text{ref}}) = \gamma\; \Delta T$ after taking $\ln$ from (1). How can I prove these two equations are equivalent?
An example of this use in a paper:
Landschützer, P., Gruber, N., Bakker, D.C.E. et al. Strengthening seasonal marine CO2 variations due to increasing atmospheric CO2. Nature Clim Change 8, 146–150 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41558-017-0057-x
More theory on this topic:
Chapter 8 in: Jorge L. Sarmiento and Nicolas Gruber. Ocean Biogeochemical Dynamics. Princeton University Press (2006) https://doi.org/10.2307/j.ctt3fgxqx

to me this looks like a first-order approximation of a difference quotient.

Not sure what "equivalent" means here.  If $\gamma\Delta T$ is small,  then $e^{\gamma \Delta T}\approx 1+\gamma \Delta T$, from the Taylor series for the exponential.  Is that what you had in mind?

Sorry my poor precision in language. By "equivalent" I mean both equations should be correct at the same time. @paulina

@lulu how small must it be? $\Delta T$ is normally maybe 1-10 °C and $\gamma = 0.0423$, so $\gamma \Delta T$ should almost always be <1. Is this small enough?

"small enough" is subjective.  You can use Taylor's Theorem with remainder to estimate the size of the error in the linear approximation, and you can see if the approximation is good enough for your purpose.  In practice, of course, people tend to just plot the approximation against the exact form and look to see whether it satisfies your goal(s).

Thank you a lot @lulu!
